# Safari 8 leftbound URL with favicon

Tags: safari, settings

In version 8 of safari the URL of a webpage is displayed centered in the adress-field, and the favicon (or apple-touch-icon) is invisible.

Only when I click into the adress-field the URL moves to the left edge and the favicon becomes visible.

What must I do to **always** have the URL displayed leftbound with the favicon visible?

This is what I've got now, but don't like:
[image: status quo]

This is what I want:
[image]
How can I get it?

btw:
Is there a way to display favicons in the tabs? sometimes its hard to navigate through many open tabs when there is nothing but text. Favicons in the tabs would be very helpful.

### Edit:

If this is impossible, it would be nice to read this in an informed answer, just to have clarity.

Comment: If only you could trade SE rep for new Apple features...

Answer (score -2):

You can show the full URL in the address field by going to to Safari > Preferences > Advanced and check the box "Show full website address." This won't, however, show the website favicon, but it's better than nothing in my opinion.

Comment: This is not what I've asked. Look at the picture under the text "This is what I've got now" and you will see that I've already done what you proposed.

Comment: Do you feel better now that you downvoted my answer? I'll remember to ignore all of your posts in the future.

Comment: ??? What's wrong with you? You did not answer my question, instead you gave an answer to a question nobody has asked. So I downvoted your answer, and I told you why I downvoted it. What else did you expect? This is nothing against you as a person. I even don't know you. It's against a wrong answer. So take it like the man you are and don't whimper like a sulky preschooler.

Comment: Hubert is right, this doesn't answer the proposed question. Ian, this is not your average phpBB forum. A downvote means your answer is invalid, not that you're a bad contributor overall. The minute you take it as personal, you're downvoting yourself as a contributor.